# Mounts only 700 MB of 536 GB partition?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning

cfdisk reports two partitions of 536 GB and 858 GB. I mount both with:

```
  mount /dev/...  /path
```

The second mounts correctly. According to df -h, the first partition contains only 850 MB.

How can I fix this?

Comment: what does `lsblk` say?

Comment: more helpful may be lsblk -amD